# Unable to connect to test.salesforce.com with SSL

Tags: php, soap, ssl, openssl, macports

I'm having some problems connecting to a SOAP Service at https://test.salesforce.com. I use the Toolkit-for-PHP v20.0 (https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-PHP) which is based on PHP's native SoapClient.

Software:

- MacOS 10.8
- Macports 2.1.2
- PHP 5.3.15
- OpenSSL 1.0.1_c

The only error message I receive after 30 seconds (timeout?) is:

```
[SoapFault]                
Could not connect to host
```

Strangely, connecting to http://test.salesforce.com (without SSL) or connecting to https://login.salesforce.com (with SSL) works as expected.

I even managed to log into https://test.salesforce.com using soapUI.

So my guess is there has to be some certification/handshake problem but i can't figure out how to get a more detailed error message or how to change anything about the toolkit setup.
I searched google, stackoverflow and the SalesForce discussion boards but nobody seems to have this specific sandbox+SSL problem.

Does anyone have a clue how to debug this problem?

---

OK, i think it's an issue with macports' openssl binary. Apparently the handshake fails because my client is attempting a SSLv2/SSLv3 handshake which the server does not understand.

```
openssl s_client -connect test.salesforce.com:443 -state
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A

[...end...]
```

Same command with forced SSLv3:

```
openssl s_client -ssl3 -connect test.salesforce.com:443 -state
CONNECTED(00000003)
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server hello A
depth=1 O = VeriSign Trust Network, OU = "VeriSign, Inc.", OU = VeriSign International Server CA - Class 3, OU = www.verisign.com/CPS Incorp.by Ref. LIABILITY LTD.(c)97 VeriSign
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A

[...and so forth...]
```

Not really sure what to make out of this... the SalesForce toolkit-for-php uses PHP's native SoapClient and I don't know how to force it to use SSLv3.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909232/php-soapclient-stream-context-option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug of the latest versions of macports' port of openssl 1.0.1:

http://trac.macports.org/ticket/33715

Possible solution: install an older openssl version, in this case openssl 1.0.0h:

```
cd /opt/local/src
sudo svn checkout -r 90715 http://svn.macports.org/repository/macports/trunk/dports/devel/openssl
cd openssl
sudo port install
```

Taken from:

- https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort
- http://trac.macports.org/ticket/33715#comment:30