# WAMPServer craahes on wsdl load at https://

Tags: https, wsdl, wampserver, win64

I've just downloaded wampserver with Apache/2.4.4 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.4.12. Not a standard download, the original openssl version was too old.

I'm trying to create a new soapclient, but when the wsdl is at an ssl url apache crashes with no error.

$wsdl = 'https://www.undisclosedlocation.com/wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl";
$sclient = new SoapClient($wsdl,array('trace'=>1));

no hits, no runs, no errors. All i get is:
The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

on the browser. Even in my debugger i just "session prematurely finished"

The wsdl isn't available on a url without ssl, but if i copy it to a local location it works, but then all the namespaces are off.

I'm using a self-signed certificate and get one more error.

[Sun Apr 13 22:45:50.192400 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 19:tid 76] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for mydomain:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is with your certifcate. There are at leas two problems:

1. Self signed certificate, which is not trusted by your client
2. The certificate doesn't contain the DNS name of your website

Most of the systems will discard the connection when one of those errors occurs.

Try to add the following setting before:

```
$context = stream_con**strong text**text_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
     )
));
```

See the following Stackoverflow question: [Disable certificate verification in PHP SoapClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443618/disable-certificate-verification-in-php-soapclient)

Comment: The server that has the wsdl has a good certificate, it's the client i'm running on that has the self-signed client. 
If i don't use new mySoap($wsdl, array()) then the wsdl doesn't seem to get parsed, and any call to a method in the wsdl fails.
Unless I'm not understanding how 'location' and 'uri' are used in the options array.