# php soapclient wsdl SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have googled and looked here in stackoverflow but I have not found a solution to my specific problem. I keep getting the error

```
 SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldnt load from "https://sampleurl.com/MerchantQueryService.asmx?WSDL" : failed to load external entity "https://sampleurl.com/MerchantQueryService.asmx?WSDL"
```

I am trying to use a SOAP API with a URL like

```
https://sampleurl.com/MerchantQueryService.asmx?WSDL
```

I am running MAMP on my localhost and using godaddy shared hosting, I have tried on both with the wsdl file can be found here

```
http://clemdemo.com/test.wsdl
```

In PHP I use the code below

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);

echo "<pre>";

try {

$url     = "https://sampleurl.com/MerchantQueryService.asmx?WSDL ";
$headers = [
    'Host: sampleurl.com',
    'Connection: Keep-Alive',
    'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.3.29',
    'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction: "RequestTransaction"',
    'Content-Length: 409'];

$rq = [
"userName" => "username_here",
"passWord" => "password_here",
"referenceId" => "3455566694",
"msisdn" => "346774313"];


try {

$cient = new SoapClient($url,
    [
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'trace' => 1,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => $headers)))
]);

print_r($cient);
} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    echo "\nFault Code: ".$e->faultcode;
    echo "\nFault String: ".$e->faultstring;
}
```

On my MAMP localhost i have SOAP,openssl and curl.

ALSO, I tried using (sending request) to the API with an online WSDL http://wsdlbrowser.com it WORKS but on code using PHP it fails

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It often happens that providers neglect their SSL certificates and hence the sites and services end up having an invalid certificates - I suspect this is the case here.

Disabling the certificate validation as described [by Kaii here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443618/disable-certificate-verification-in-php-soapclient) or even better get your provider to fix their certificate.

Your code could/should then be something like:

```
$url     = "https://sampleurl.com/MerchantQueryService.asmx?WSDL ";
$context = stream_context_create(array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
));

$rq = ["userName" => "username_here",
       "passWord" => "password_here",
       "referenceId" => "3455566694",
       "msisdn" => "346774313"];

$service = new SoapClient($url, array('stream_context' => $context));
$service->RequestTransaction($rq);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message appears to say that your app is not able to read our WSDL. Try opening a browser from the same machine on which your app is running and see if you can access the WSDL address at https://sampleurl.com/MerchantQueryService.asmx?WSDL.

If not - you have a network/firewall/Anti Virus problem. (in case)

If you can access this address from a browser - is your app still experiencing this problem? then check any app that could be hindering your firewall.(Anti virus are most probable cause)

Answer (score 1):

If you use docker there is a chance you get error because of OpenSSL default security level. **Even if you disable verify and allow self-signed in SoapClient options.**

Try out to lower seclevel in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` from `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2` to

```
DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Or just add into Dockerfile

```
RUN sed -i "s|DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2|DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1|g" /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

By: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30667#issuecomment-566482876

---

You can verify it by run on container

```sh
curl -A 'cURL User Agent' -4 https://ewus.nfz.gov.pl/ws-broker-server-ewus/services/Auth?wsdl
```

Answer (score -1):

- Better diagnostics can be performed with:  libxml_get_last_error();
- Could have cached a bad response, set 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE when initating the object
- if you skip cache, and get this in your libxml error:

  LibXMLError Object
  (
      [level] => 1
      [code] => 1549
      [column] => 0
      [message] => failed to load external entity "URL"
      [file] => 
      [line] => 0
  )

With no description on Ubuntu, then its not pulling the file period. You just got hit with the Ubuntu update. Wave them the bronx salute and reboot.