# PHP: SoapClient Error When I Using Custom Port

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

When I use port with URL I get error:

Code:

```
    try {
        $options = [
            'login' => "999999",
            'password' => "999999testtest"
        ];
        $request = new SoapClient("https://erpefaturatest.cs.com.tr:8043/efatura/ws/connectorService?wsdl", $options);
        print_r($request);
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        print_r($exc);
    }
```

Error:
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

But wihthout port I don't get error:

Code:

```
    try {
        $options = [
            'login' => "999999",
            'password' => "999999testtest"
        ];
        $request = new SoapClient("https://connectortest.efinans.com.tr/connector/ws/connectorService?wsdl", $options);
        print_r($request);
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        print_r($exc);
    }
```

I don't understand the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure why it would be the case with your example, but most of these questions are tied to SSL. Could just try setting all the `verify_` options to false to see if it works. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33976391/php-soapclient-wsdl-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from). I know that doesn't fit well with what you are showing. I mean you can say use curl and load that WSDL from the machine where the code runs?

Comment: i tried curl. It is also failed. I think the problem is with the port. But I don't know the solution.