# Call a SOAP web service with HTTPS without certificates

Tags: ssl, soap, https, soapui, tibco-business-works

I want to call a third party web service from TIBCO BW6.X via **SOAP** over **HTTPS** by using basic authentication.

I can do it with SOAPUI just by adding authorization as a HTTP header with the key (like `Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpPcGVuU2VzYW1`) and it works fine. But using BW, I have to create an SSL resource with certifcates to use HTTPS.

My question is : Can I connect to a web service using HTTPS URL without SSL/certificates? If yes, then how? else, why can I do it with SOAPUI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on the soap client you are using. Basically you need just ignore the certificate validation as far as i interpret your question.

Example for php:

[Disable certificate verification in PHP SoapClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443618/disable-certificate-verification-in-php-soapclient)

Comment: thanks for your response, I'm looking how to do it in my case.

Comment: let me know if it works for you, if not please edit your question so i can edit my answer accordingly

Comment: I don't find how to do it with Tibco BW

Comment: No clue about Tibco itself, you might ask their support. In worst case you can always set up a proxy that runs on http instead of https and the proxy forwards the request to the target server and the response back to the caller